# Memory Leak on scaling image in iOS using SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have an app that displays images and scales them to certain size.
Here is the code for the scaling:

```
static func scaledImage(originalImage image: UIImage, scaledToSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage {        
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0.0)
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return scaledImage
}
```

and here is how the call to the function is being made:

```
for i in 0 ..< images.count{
    if let data = images[i].imageData, let originalImage = UIImage(data: data) {
        previewImage = scaledImage(originalImage: originalImage, scaledToSize: desiredSize)            
    } 
}
```

The app was crashing for 50 images 
When i used instruments to find where the memory was allocated it told me that this line allocates 960 MB:
image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))

and that is quite a lot of memory.

So my question is what is being done wrong here?
How to solve that memory leak.

I searched through lots of examples on how to scale images but they were more or less the same. There was no example on memory management and due to the fact that i do not have lots of experience in image processing i have no idea how to approach this problem.

Any help here will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't necessarily a leak. Images take up quite a bit of memory, and if you're holding 50 of them (and the 50 resized versions) in memory at the same time, you're probably going to have a bad time. Memory size of an image in memory is generally width * height * 4 bytes. What sizes were the original images and their resized versions? Multiply the above times 50 for each size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The Original images are FULL HD. Is there a way to optimise the solution so it works better. An also how to release the memory that has been allocated by the graphics context ?

Comment: 1080p frames are 8.3 MB in size each. 50 of those would take up 415 MB of memory (even 50 MB of allocations like this would kill your application on older iOS devices). Don't load all 50 images into memory at once. Load and resize each image on demand, maintaining at most a cache of a couple of images.  When done with an image, make sure you're not holding onto a reference to it.

Comment: You have to autorelease the call to scaledImage.

Comment: The autorelease poll did the job. @Darko thank you. You can add your comment as a answer so i can accept it

Comment: Sure, you are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to autorelease the call to scaledImage.

```
autoreleasepool {
  previewImage = scaledImage(originalImage: originalImage, scaledToSize: desiredSize)
}
```

Comment: The autoreleasepool didn't work for me. I just lose 40MB or so every time I call

Comment: Update: The autoreleasepool only worked if I wrapped the entire loop with it. I just lost 40MB or so every time I scaled inside the loop and ran out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

if you do hundreds or thousands you’ll see that “UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext” will hold onto the image in memory until the code returns control to the runloop, which may not happen for a long time. This may lead to crashes when iOS decides your app is using too much memory.

here’s the implementation of the autorelease pool code:

```
func scaledImage(originalImage image: UIImage, scaledToSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    return autoreleasepool { () -> UIImage in
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0.0)
        image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return scaledImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem and after trying various solutions, I tried using autoreleasepool and it did't help... and after a while I came across the following insights:

When dealing with images using UIImage and CGImage system methods, it consumes a significant amount of memory. For instance, a simple image with dimensions around 4000px x 3000px can take up approximately 45MB of memory. If your app needs to handle multiple images or if you're working with a share extension, it's possible for your app to exhaust all available memory and crash. Share extensions have a limited memory allocation of only 120MB, so sharing larger images (above 7000px in height/width) can easily lead to app crashes. This issue has even affected some of the most popular apps on iOS.

So, there is no straightforward solution other than avoiding the handling of large image files or using third-party tools.

One such open-source library that addresses this problem, (and which I used to solve this problem) is SDWebImage, available at https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage. After importing this library into your project, you can use it to handle images without worrying about memory leaks or crashes.

Here's an example of how you can use SDWebImage in your project to resize or compress image:

```
func resizeImage(atPath imagePath: URL) -> UIImage? {
    guard let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath.path) else { return nil }
    
    guard let thumbnailData = SDImageIOCoder.shared.encodedData(with: image, format: .undefined, options: [.encodeMaxPixelSize: CGSize(width: 1920, height: 1920), .encodeCompressionQuality: 0.7]) else { return nil }
    
    return SDImageIOCoder.shared.decodedImage(with: thumbnailData)
}
```